# Jquery clear all selected options not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select dropdown with few options. When I try to select one option using jquery, I see in html source, that the selected option has "selected = selected" as attribute.

When I tried to select one more option through jquery then it also added option as "selected = selected" as attribute.

But it added 2 options as selected in html source. I tried to remove selected options though code but it never worked.

How can I removed selected= selected attribute for all options in a dropdown?

I tried the below options but nothing worked

```
    $('select[id^="myDropdown"]').find('option:selected').removeProp("selected");
    $('select[id^="myDropdown"]').find('option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
$('select[id^="myDropdown"]').removeAttr('selected');
$('select[id^="myDropdown"] option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
$('select[id^="myDropdown"] option:selected').removeProp('selected');
$('select[id^="myDropdown"] option:selected').prop('selected',false);
```

Basic Jquery code

```
$(document).on("click", ".list-group a", function () {
var selected = $(this).text();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class=".list-group">
<a id="clickMeTOSelectOption">test 1</a>
<a id="clickMeTOSelectOption">test 2</a>
<a id="clickMeTOSelectOption">test 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Options can't be deselected as such. You can only select another option. You can do so with jQuery's `.val(...)` or in POJS by setting a select element's `.selectedIndex` property.

Comment: Sorry, I've just realised you are talking about a `<select multiple>` element, aren't you?

Comment: Sorry, its not a multi dropdown. Its a single dropdown but when I am trying to dynamically make the option to select using jquery, it selects options but it is not removing the selected option when I select another value. So now my drop down in html shows multiple selected="selected" attributes for options in select.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic `<select>` element**

A basic `<select>` menu always has exactly one option selected. The selected options can be deselected by selecting another option.

This can be achieved with jQuery as follows ...

```
$('#mySelect').val('someValue');
```

... or with POJS as follows :

```
mySelectElemlent.selectedIndex = 3; // some zero-based index
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/s7gh9uhq/3/)**

**`<select multiple>` element**

A `<select multiple>` menu behaves differently. Its selected options can be seleted/deselected independently of other options.

```
$('#mySelectMultiple option').eq(1).prop('selected', false);
$('#mySelectMultiple option').eq(3).prop('selected', true);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/s7gh9uhq/20/)**

**Note**: with a basic `<select>`, the effect of `.prop('selected', false);` is indeterminate (it's not specified). In most (maybe all) browsers, the first (0th) option will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code.

```js
var select = $('#myDropdown');
select.children('option').prop('selected',false);
select.selectpicker('refresh');
```

I did not try the code. If there are any mistakes, go back.

Comment: is selectpicker inbuilt?

Comment: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ you can look over here.

Comment: I think it will be better if you send all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to iterate over all drop down options and remove the attribute. Thanks for every ones help.

```
$("#myDropDown > option").each(function () {
   this.removeAttribute("selected");
});
```

Comment: If you need to do this, then you must be doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: could you please eloborate?

Comment: The natural behaviour of a basic select menu is for exactly one option to be selected at all times. It's hard to see why the selected attribute might need to be set/tested/removed when the `.selectedIndex` property and jQuery's `.val()` are thoroughly reliable.